# How to make a Menu that goes from the header to the footer?

Tags: html, css, layout, menu

So, I am learning how to code HTML5, CSS3, and all that good stuff. But I have an issue the book doesn't solve. As you may be able to see, The Nav area doesn't go from the header to the footer. I was hoping someone could help me understand how to get it to go from the header to the footer. Maybe it's just a simple padding. But I don't wanna mess up the layout. Hope I am not asking a stupid question.

```css
/*HEADER*/

header {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

/*BODY*/

nav {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 20%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}


section {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
article {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="semanticTags.css"/>
    <title>
      Semantic Tags
    </title>
    <body>
      <header>
        <h1>This is my header</h1>
      </header>
      
      <nav>
        <h2>Navigation</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="google.com">Google</a></li>
          <li><a href="Bing.com">Bing</a></li>
          <li><a href="Yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
          <li><a href="Aol.com">AOL</a></li>
          <li><a href="Facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      
      <section id="1">
        <h2>
          Section 1
        </h2>
        <p>
          Section Body
        </p>
      </section>
      
      <section id="2">
        <h2>
          Section 2
        </h2>
        <p>
          Section Body
        </p>
      </section>
      
      <article>
        <h2>
          Article
        </h2>
        <p>
          Article Body
        </p>
      </article>
      
      <footer>
        <h2>footer</h2>
        <address>
          DreamRiskers<br>
          <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">
            email@gmail.com
          </a>
        </address>
      </footer>
      
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use position:fixed; css property set nav top to bottom. Below code will help you to get expected output.

```css
/*HEADER*/

header {
  border: 3px solid black;
 margin-left:21%;
}

/*BODY*/

nav {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 20%;
  border: 3px solid black;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 height:100%;
}


section {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 21%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
article {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 21%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  border: 3px solid black;
 margin-left:21%;
}
```

```html
      <header>
        <h1>This is my header</h1>
      </header>
      
      <nav>
        <h2>Navigation</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="google.com">Google</a></li>
          <li><a href="Bing.com">Bing</a></li>
          <li><a href="Yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
          <li><a href="Aol.com">AOL</a></li>
          <li><a href="Facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      
      <section id="1">
        <h2>
          Section 1
        </h2>
        <p>
          Section Body
        </p>
      </section>
      
      <section id="2">
        <h2>
          Section 2
        </h2>
        <p>
          Section Body
        </p>
      </section>
      
      <article>
        <h2>
          Article
        </h2>
        <p>
          Article Body
        </p>
      </article>
      
      <footer>
        <h2>footer</h2>
        <address>
          DreamRiskers<br>
          <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">
            email@gmail.com
          </a>
        </address>
      </footer>
```

Comment: I tried what you have added, and I am getting a mess. The NAV is overlapping the Header instead of connecting to it. The footer is pushed to the side and not at the bottom. Maybe I didn't explain exactly what I wanted. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There may be two ways that i can advise :

1. in your `html file`, add :

> < body `class="nav"` >

and in your `css file`, make :

> `.`nav {
>   float: left;
>                clear: both;
>
> ```
>   width: 100%;
>   height: 100%;
> ```
>
> border: 3px solid black;
>   background-color:yellow; }

*background-color* is just for distinguishing.

2. in your `html file`, put `<nav>` tag just after `<body>` tag, and 
                            `</nav>` tag just before `</body>` tag

   and make your `css file` as follows :

> nav {
>   float: left;
>                clear: both;
>
> ```
>   width: 100%;
>   height: 100%;
> ```
>
> border: 3px solid black;
>   background-color:yellow; }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. So I wasn't paying attention to where the `<header>` tag was. For some reason on my file, the header was below the `<nav>` tags. So after putting the `<header>` tag before the `<nav>`

Thank you for trying to help me tho. :)

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 3px double black;
}

/*BODY*/

nav {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 15%;
  min-height: 400px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}


section {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
article {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  border-top: 3px double black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="semanticTags.css"/>
    <title>
      Semantic Tags
    </title>
    <body class="nav">
      <header>
        <h1>This is my header</h1>
      </header>
      <nav>
        <h2>Navigation</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="google.com">Google</a></li>
          <li><a href="Bing.com">Bing</a></li>
          <li><a href="Yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
          <li><a href="Aol.com">AOL</a></li>
          <li><a href="Facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      
      
      
      
      <section id="1">
        <h2>
          Section 1
        </h2>
        <p>
          Section Body
        </p>
      </section>
      
      <section id="2">
        <h2>
          Section 2
        </h2>
        <p>
          Section Body
        </p>
      </section>
      
      <article>
        <h2>
          Article
        </h2>
        <p>
          Article Body
        </p>
      </article>
      
      <footer>
        <h2>footer</h2>
        <address>
          DreamRiskers<br>
          <a href="mailto:Email@gmail.com">
            Email@gmail.com
          </a>
        </address>
      </footer>
      
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```